# Knockout.js select list acting erratically on ios

Tags: knockout.js, ios6, cordova, safari

I have a few select boxes that are acting erratically in ios.  I'm running cordova 1.8.1 and have a knockout.js application running on my page.  When I select an item in the item picker, it gets selected but so do all the other items on the list.  Now, as far as I can tell the proper item is being selected and reported when I submit the form, but it looks really really bad to the user and could be very confusing.  I'm doing anything fancy, here is the code:

```
<select class="dropdownList1" style='width:35%;left:28%;position:absolute;' data-bind="value:ContactUsForm.Month,options:ContactUsForm.Months,optionsCaption: 'Month'"></select>
```

But here is the result when I pick 7 for the month:

[image]

This is NOT a muti select box.  It seems to me that the error here is in iOS, but my suspicion is that Knockout is also doing some re rendering when I select a value.  In normal browsers the box snaps shut so you never see an 'intermediate' state, but with ios, the box stays open until you click 'done'.

Comment: This issue happens on our website also. Any solutions or workaround so far?

Comment: There is an open issue for this on knockout: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/472

Comment: What happens if you remove the `value` binding?

Comment: If value binding is removed, it does not have this rendering issue !!

Answer (score 5):

This problem is caused when Knockout updates the items in the drop-down. But even if `ContactUsForm.Months` never changes, Knockout still updates the items whenever the value changes, such as when you select an item. See [RP Niemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594420/rp-niemeyer)'s article [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #3 - All Bindings Fire Together](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html) for more details on this problem.

I think a solution he presents there will work for you. Instead of using the `options` binding, you should use his `isolatedOptions` binding. (Also the `value` binding should always be after `options` or `isolatedOptions`.)

```
<select data-bind="
    isolatedOptions:ContactUsForm.Months, optionsCaption:'Month', 
    value:ContactUsForm.Month"></select>
```

Comment: Tested and it fixed the issue

Comment: Knockout 2.3.0 or 3.0.0 beta should fix this without the need to change your code.