# jQuery Mobile and Knockoutjs: select list acts like multiple when the number of options exceeds some limit

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm having a select element bound to an observableArray. When the array length exceeds some limit (I think 3 is minimum), the select turns into a select with multiple choices. Happens on iPhone 5.

Here the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrian_iftode/RGWhx/3/)

And here an image of what's happening.

[image]

Comment: I answered this same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12943414/1287183

Comment: @MichaelBest, yes working, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout.js select list acting erratically on ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802896/knockout-js-select-list-acting-erratically-on-ios)