# Knockout.js issue on iPhone - drop down list issue

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, knockout.js

I'm having some trouble with Knockout.js when running on an iPhone. The problem seems to be specific to html select controls. The phone gets into a state where the picker (i.e. iOS drop down) has multiple items selected.

Please see a working example here;
http://jsfiddle.net/robjwalker/Wep67/22/

To repeat;

- Browse on an iPhone in portrait,
- Select a colour from the list,
- Notice 2 items are selected/ticked,
- Turn the phone into landscape,
- All items are selected!

I'm handling the change event of the drop down with the function at the bottom of the script. This function changes the view model upon which the drop down depends. In turn, Knockout.js is forcing this update down to the view (i.e. updating the drop down list).

I have tried the isolatedOption suggestion proposed as a solution to a similar problem - unfortunately this doesn't seem to help. More details here;
[Knockout.js select list acting erratically on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802896/knockout-js-select-list-acting-erratically-on-ios)

Thanks in advance for any assistance,
Rob.

P.S. Here is an example of the html binding code - please see js fiddle link above for a working example.

```
<select id="colourSelect" 
data-bind="isolatedOptions: colours,
optionsText: 'name', 
optionsValue: 'id', 
optionsCaption: 'Please select...',
value: selectedColour">
</select>
```

Comment: I managed to get this working for my own purposes by replacing property values of elements inside the observable array. This was ok in my case as the same number of items always comes down (just with slightly different values). Apparently items in the observable array are not observable in their own right by default - so as long as your not adding/removing items from the collection, you'll get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another fix, this is a known bug in the knockout bindings.

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/472